# how to fix transactionPaymentApi.queryInfo runtime call issue?

Tags: polkadot-js, runtime, rpc, substrate-front-end, transaction-fees

`api.tx.balances.transfer(recipient, new BN(txAmount)).paymentInfo(sender)`
When I call paymentinfo to get a transaction fee, I got this error.
`Error: The transactionPaymentApi.queryInfo runtime call is not available in your environment`

Comment: What chain are you querying?

Comment: which version of polkadot.js are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I used 9.6.2, just upgraded the @polkadot/api to the latest version and it worked as expected.
Thank you  @Tarik Gul and @pepoviola